# Change header title in beamer

Tags: beamer, header-footer, parts

I'm preparing a presentation with three parts. I use Antibes theme.
I want to change the title of the presentation that appears in each frame by the title of the part, and then the sections and subsections.
Now I have, in frames header:

Title of the presentation
Section
Subsection

And I want

Title of the part
Section
Subsection

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can help us to help you by providing the code for a small document that shows your setup, including the theme you use. Just edit your question and add the code.

Comment: If you don't know how to provide a minimal working example, look [here](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Answer (score 1):

If you redefine the headline template, you can replace `\insertshorttitle` with `\insertpart`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Antibes}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,colsep=1.5pt]{upper separation line head}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,%
      leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{title in head/foot}
      \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}%
      \insertpart
%      \insertshorttitle
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,%
      leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{section in head/foot}
      \usebeamerfont{section in head/foot}%
      \ifbeamer@tree@showhooks
        \setbox\beamer@tempbox=\hbox{\insertsectionhead}%
        \ifdim\wd\beamer@tempbox>1pt%
          \hskip2pt\raise1.9pt\hbox{\vrule width0.4pt height1.875ex\vrule width 5pt height0.4pt}%
          \hskip1pt%
        \fi%
      \else%  
        \hskip6pt%
      \fi%
      \insertsectionhead
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,%
      leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{subsection in head/foot}
      \usebeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}%
      \ifbeamer@tree@showhooks
        \setbox\beamer@tempbox=\hbox{\insertsubsectionhead}%
        \ifdim\wd\beamer@tempbox>1pt%
          \hskip9.4pt\raise1.9pt\hbox{\vrule width0.4pt height1.875ex\vrule width 5pt height0.4pt}%
          \hskip1pt%
        \fi%
      \else%  
        \hskip12pt%
      \fi%
      \insertsubsectionhead
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,colsep=1.5pt]{lower separation line head}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
}

\makeatother


\title{title}
\begin{document}


\part{part}
\section{section}
\subsection{subsection}
\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

[image]